# Configuration management sync vs active vs staging

Tags: 8, configuration

The [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/administer/config) on config management talks about a `CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY` setting, but then there is also mention of `CONFIG_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY` and `CONFIG_STAGING_DIRECTORY` setting throughout comments both on d.o and in stack overflow.

What are these two different setups about?

Comment: Hrm. I like both answers from 4k4 and anavarre below, and don't know which one to give credit to.  The first one from 4k4 has code samples but no links.  And the second one has ample links and no code sample.  I'm also not sure how credit works if anavarre were to remove his answer, and propose a suggested edit to 4k4's answer and I credited that one, would you both get equal points?

Answer (score 7):

This has changed, before Drupal beta 14 it was active/staging now it is sync. These are the settings in settings.php:

```
Drupal 8 beta 14:
$config_directories['active'] = 'sites/default/files/config_HASH/active';
$config_directories['staging'] = 'sites/default/files/config_HASH/staging';

Drupal 8 rc1:
$config_directories['sync'] = 'sites/default/files/config_HASH/sync';
```

Answer (score 5):

Timely question. This is being discussed at [Update documentation that mentions active CMI directory. active was removed.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2580569) Reviewing the documentation in the patch should clarify everything.

Long story short: [staging has been replaced by sync](https://www.drupal.org/node/2574957) and [active is no longer created by default](https://www.drupal.org/node/2501187).